# How can I set previously selected date as the default date on next open of DatePicker?

Tags: android, datepicker, android-edittext

If EditText line has a previously selected date (length test >0) then I use a Bundle to pass that date to a DatePicker Fragment.  When I next click on the EditText line to launch the DatePicker again, I expect to see the previously selected date as the default.  But I see a monthly calendar for December 1899 and the day is defaulted to "1".  What am I missing here?

partial Activity file, in onCreate:

```
else if (hasFocus && (fEditText.getText().length() > 0) && (savedInstanceState  == null)) {
     // Create a new calendar object
     Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
     // Extract the previously entered FEditText date as a string
     String dateStr = fEditText.getText().toString().replace(" ","");
     // Split the string date into parts, year, month and day.
     String[]dateParts = dateStr.split("/");
     // Parse the EditText date here to get year, month and day, and then
     // Set the Calendar date in the object to the EditText date.
     // Month is zero-based so need to subtract one from it.
     c.set(Integer.parseInt(dateParts[2]),Integer.parseInt(dateParts[0])-1,Integer.parseInt(dateParts[1]));
     // Now create a bundle to pass the date to the fragment and into the datepicker
     Bundle argsbundle = new Bundle();
     argsbundle.putInt("year", c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
     argsbundle.putInt("month", c.get(Calendar.MONTH));
     argsbundle.putInt("day", c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
     // Create a new fragment.
     DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
     // Set the year, month and day data from the bundle to the fragment.
     newFragment.setArguments(argsbundle);
     newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
     }
```

DatePickerFragment:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

Calendar c;
int year = 0, month = 0, day = 0;

public DatePickerFragment() {
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

    // If the argsbundle from the Activity has data (because the user previously selected a date) then
    // set that date in the DatePicker.
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        c = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = getArguments().getInt("year");
        month = getArguments().getInt("month");
        day = getArguments().getInt("day");
        c.set(year, month, day);
    } else { // If the DueDate EditText line is empty (no previously selected date by the user then
        // set today's date into the DatePicker.
        // Calendar class obtains the current date on the device and has fields for
        // each of the parts of the date: day, month and year.
        c = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    }

    DatePickerDialog picker = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
            this, year, month, day);
    picker.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(true);
    picker.setTitle("Select a Due Date");
    return picker;
}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
     Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
     calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,month);
     calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,day);
     // Set the selected date into the FEditText line.
     EditText txtDate = (EditText) getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().findViewById(R.id.FEditText);
     // Format the selected date.
     String myFormat = "MM/dd/yy";
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
     txtDate.setText(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
}
```

Comment: year format is in "yy" ?

Comment: yes I need to truncate the year down to "yy" so it will fit on the EditText line.  Do you think that is what is causing the problem?

Comment: you set year to `Calendar` with "yy" year format, it would set 15 to `Calendar` not 2015. Try to use "yyyy" instead of "yy". You may add `Log` to display what date pass to your fragment for debugging.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Ok, can I just convert 15 to 2015 in the Activity file?  Meaning, somehow convert the string from yy back to yyyy for the bundle?  Unfortunately if I leave in yyyy format the date won't fit on the EditText line.